# How to copy span of chars from char array to vector?

Tags: c++, stl

How to copy span of chars from char array to vector ? Starting index is always 0 and goes to some passed value x. I have char* buffer on heap ( size is 32*1024) and I am using that buffer to receive messages and set received message size in  variable x. How to copy from 0th to xth char to `vector<char> mainBuffer` ?
( I can simply iterate but it looks inefficient way if message is long. Another way is like below but then I always in every pass create new vector)

```
char* buffer = new char[32*1024];
int x;
std::vector<std::vector<char> > mainBuffer;
//:loop
// here is some code where I recive message in buffer and set x
mainBuffer.push_back(std::vector<char>(buffer,buffer+x));
//:end loop
```

Does anyone know more efficient and elegant way to do this ?

Comment: In C++11, the vector will get moved, so it isn't inefficient.

Comment: Your question confuses me. Is `mainBuffer` a `vector<char>` or a `vector<vector<char>>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mainBuffer.push_back(std::vector<char>(buffer,buffer+x));
```

> Does anyone know more efficient and elegant way to do this ?

With C++11, do:

```
mainBuffer.emplace_back( buffer,buffer+x );
```

This forwards the parameters and constructs the object directly inside mainBuffer.

Edit: With C++ (old), use std::swap:

```
mainBuffer.push_back( std::vector<char>() );
mainBuffer.back().swap( std::vector<char>(buffer, buffer+x) );
```

Edit 2: If you can, call reserve on mainBuffer before using push_back on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really are looking for efficieny, then the typical way to do this in a protocol would be:

```
char* mainBuffer = new char[veryLargeNumber]
char* mainBufferPos = mainBuffer;
char* buffer = new char[normallyASmallNumber] 
while(...) {
    ...receive n bytes in buffer....
    memcopy(mainBufferPos, buffer, n);
    mainBufferPos += n;
    if (mainBufferPos > mainBuffer+veryLargeNumber) 
        break;    // buffer full, needs probably more handling...
}
```

Normally, I would expect that 32*1024 is more the size of your large buffer, and that the messages you receive are more of a length below 1024.